# Programmatically adding new line in mx:TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, newline, flex4.5

I have a flex 4.5 application. I want to add new line in an mx:TextArea when certain event occurs. I have been searching for the proper way to add a OS independent line ending. I found out that the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class has [lineEnding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#lineEnding) property. However the documentation states that this class is not exposed when running inside a browser (which is my case).

I have searched, but I couldn't find any other class, which can provide this information. Actually I am not sure if the TextArea line ending is OS dependent or not.

So actually I have two questions: Are TextArea line endings OS dependent or not? And if so, how can I get the proper line ending in flex?

Comment: Not really an answer but it should work: you could use the [htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html#htmlText) property and mark the line breaks with a `<br/>` tag.

Comment: @RIAstar Actually I was planning on doing this, but I was just curious if there is another way to do it.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu what do you mean by "enter" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.fromCharCode(13)`. This will return a line ending.
This is the equivalent of PHP's `chr()` method.

Example:

```
var address_str:String = "dog" + String.fromCharCode(64) + "house.net";
trace(address_str); // output: dog@house.net
```

Comment: As I don't like magic numbers, I decided to use `String.fromCharCode(Keyboard.ENTER)`.

Comment: Hehe, magic numbers :p but +1 on your comment for mentioning Keyboard.ENTER

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, "\r" works in both Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you just need to add the newline character to the `text` of the textArea.

```
myTextArea.text+="\n"; //This should work, if not try the other two
myTextArea.text+="\r";
myTextArea.text+="\r\n";
```